# Upload files to azure file storage via Web API

Tags: azure, file-upload, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to upload files to our cloud storage at Azure but only get a `bad request 400` response. Running the application on local host and trying to connect to our account at Azure.

When I place this in a try/catch I get a `bad request 400` on the last line

> cloudFile.Create(fileSize);

This line below returns null, yet the file share exists when I check it in the if statement:

> var listShares = fileClient.ListShares(); // null

I've only found one example on how to actually upload a file like this:

```
// Connect to Azure Storage         
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
        CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AzureStorageConnectionString"));

    //Create a CloudFileClient object for credentialed access to File storage.
    CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

    //Get a reference to the file share we created previously.
    CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("appbackup");

    var listShares = fileClient.ListShares();

    //Ensure that the share exists.
    if (share.Exists())
    {
        //Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
        CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();

        //Get a reference to the sampledir directory we created previously.
        CloudFileDirectory sampleDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference("sampledir");

        //Ensure that the directory exists.
        if (sampleDir.Exists())
        {
            var test = rootDir.ListFilesAndDirectories();
            var Credentials = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials("accountName", "keyValue");

            string stringUri = storageAccount.FileStorageUri.PrimaryUri + share.Name + "/sampledir/";

            Uri theUri = new Uri(stringUri);
            CloudFile cloudFile = new CloudFile(theUri, Credentials);
            System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(filepath);
            long fileSize = fi.Length;
            cloudFile.Create(fileSize);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's an issue in your code here:

```
string stringUri = storageAccount.FileStorageUri.PrimaryUri + share.Name + "/sampledir/";
```

You're not adding the file name to the `stringUri`. Please try by adding the name of the file to `stringUri` and that should do the trick.

Comment: Oh, yes, that might have been it! Now I only have to check if the file actually exists where I uploaded it...another adventure.

Answer (score 0):

Well I struggled for ages because I could not find a good sample. Eventually I found out that it is so simple you would not believe it.

The following does not upload from a file but does upload from a stream so I'm sure you can join the dots to figure out how to do get a stream for a file and use that instead.

```
    private static void CreateSampleFile(CloudFileDirectory sampleDir, string fileName)
    {
        CloudFile file = sampleDir.GetFileReference(fileName);

        using (Stream s = GenerateStreamFromString(string.Format("It is {0}", DateTime.Now)))
        {
            file.UploadFromStream(s);
        }
    }
```

The key thing that tripped me up is the call to GetFileReference on the containing folder. You call this and then UploadFromStream does the rest for you. The GenerateStreamFromString() method is an answer to another question on here about how to convert strings to streams and is not really relevant to this question.